# How to get response header using ActionScript? (Flash)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, url, header, mxml

So... I have a URL like www.example.com/stream/

I need to make any request to this url and get Http Rewspons header (like this one:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-type: video/x-flv
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I do not need reponse body at all. After I get header need to emmidiatly close connection to that url (so stop to obtain data from it)

How to do such thing (I use Flash builder)

Comment: Where you able to verify the answer? We still seem to be getting an empty array for the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparently, that's possible in AIR (I've never tried it):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLStream.html#event:httpResponseStatus

The only other way I can think of is using a [Socket](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/Socket.html)  directly. It's more involved though, and there are some security related issues that are a PITA.