# Get headers from a Coldfusion Flash Remoting RemoteObject to Flex

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3, apache-flex, coldfusion, rpc

For some reason, i can't manage to get any headers from a Coldfusion Flash Remoting RemoteObject call in Flex no matter what i try. The headers are always null in both the ResultEvent and the token. Not sure if i am missing something or it is impossible at all? I have seen discussion where people say it is only possible to send headers for a normal HTTP request but also seen discussions about headers for RPC. My main goal is to get a cookie from an RPC call (a session id alone will not help).

The Facade is the standard Coldfusion setup configured in Project Settigns > Flex Server:

```
_serviceControl = new mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject();
_serviceControl.operations = operations;
_serviceControl.convertResultHandler = com.adobe.serializers.utility.TypeUtility.convertResultHandler;
_serviceControl.convertParametersHandler = com.adobe.serializers.utility.TypeUtility.convertCFAMFParametersHandler;
_serviceControl.source = "facade.globalFacade";
_serviceControl.endpoint = "https://...";
```

The call from Flex goes like

```
_loginCallResponder = new CallResponder();
_loginCallResponder.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onLoginResult);
_loginCallResponder.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, onLoginFault);
_loginCallResponder.token = _globalFacade.globalDmSec(ApplicationConstants.TOKEN, "LOGIN", "singleSignOn", {}, 30, false);
```

The coldfusion part has the setMaintainSession set to true:

```
<cfset variables.oWs = createObject("webservice",variables.wsName)>
  <cfset variables.oWs.setMaintainSession(true)>
```

Any help and tips is highly appreciated :)
Thank you !

Comment: Not sure this is possilbe. What version of CF are you using? (Psst. contact me if you want some flex work :)

Comment: @MarkAKruger - shameless plug.  ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get response header using ActionScript? (Flash)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733853/how-to-get-response-header-using-actionscript-flash)